# Compare two lists from user

Tags: c#, regex, string, linq

I have a predefined list List words.Say it has 7 elements:

```
List<string> resourceList={"xyz","dfgabr","asxy", "abec","def","geh","mnbj"}
```

Say, the user gives an input "xy+ ab" i.e he wants to search for "xy" or "ab"

```
string searchword="xy+ ab";
```

Then I have to find all the words in the predefined list which have "xy" or "ab" i.e all words split by '+'

So, the output will have:

```
{"xyz","dfgabr","abec",""}
```

I am trying something like:

```
resourceList.Where(s => s.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchWords.Any().ToString().ToLower())).ToList()
```

But, I am unable to frame the LINQ query as there are 2 arrays and one approach I saw was concatenate 2 arrays and then try; but since my second array only contains part of the first array, my LINQ does not work.

Comment: I edited your question and added the new information. Please remember to always include all the relevant information [into the question itself](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55794045/edit).

Comment: your variable "searchword" will it be regex?

Comment: Is the space after the `+` in `searchword` (shouldn't that be `searchwords`?) to be ignored? Why doesn't the output have `asxy`? Why does the output have an empty string?

Comment: Thanks all for your valuable comments and solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first split your search pattern with `+` sign and then you can easily find out which are those item in list that contains your search pattern,

```
var result = resourceList.Where(x => searchword.Split('+').Any(y => x.Contains(y.Trim()))).ToList();
```

**Where:**

Your `resourceList` is

```
List<string> resourceList = new List<string> { "xyz", "dfgabr", "asxy", "abec", "def", "geh", "mnbj" };
```

And search pattern is,

```
string searchword = "xy+ ab";
```

**Output:** (From Debugger)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try querying with a help of *Linq*:

```
List<string> resourceList = new List<string> {
  "xyz", "dfgabr", "asxy", "abec", "def", "geh", "mnbj"
};

string input = "xy+ ab";

string[] toFind = input
  .Split('+')
  .Select(item => item.Trim()) // we are looking for "ab", not for " ab"
  .ToArray();

// {"xyz", "dfgabr", "asxy", "abec"}
string[] result = resourceList
  .Where(item => toFind
     .Any(find => item.IndexOf(find) >= 0))
  .ToArray();
 
// Let's have a look at the array
Console.Write(string.Join(", ", result));
```

**Outcome:**

```
xyz, dfgabr, asxy, abec
```

If you want to *ignore case*, add `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` parameter to `IndexOf`

```
string[] result = resourceList
  .Where(item => toFind
     .Any(find => item.IndexOf(find, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0))
  .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following which doesn't need Regex :

```
            List<string> resourceList= new List<string>() {"xyz","dfgabr","asxy","abec","def","geh","mnbj"};
            List<string> searchPattern = new List<string>() {"xy","ab"};

            List<string> results = resourceList.Where(r => searchPattern.Any(s => r.Contains(s))).ToList();
```